# SQL query to insert same value 1000 times without loop

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

For example, if I have string 'sunday', then I want to insert same value in 1000 rows using SQL only; without using loops.

Comment: you need to use sql loops

Comment: Can you explain with an example, so that is understanable what you need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use another table you can use:

```
    INSERT INTO some_table (some_column) 
    SELECT 'Sunday'
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d1
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d2
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d3
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d4
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d5
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d6
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d7
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d8
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d9
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d10
    ) AS t
    LIMIT 1000
```

You can adjust the amount of JOIN's depending on the limit you want.

Comment: this works... but why, why is this more desirable than using a loop?

Comment: It's probably faster than using a single row insert in a loop. Other than that is because that's what was asked for (SQL only, no loops).

Comment: @Vatev indeed but context/reasoning can still be important, otherwise you could be providing a correct answer to the wrong question.

Comment: @HmanshuUpadhyay please accept the answer if it answered your question.  More info at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a table that has more than a 1000 rows, you could do

```
insert into mytable (mycolumn) select "Sunday" from mytablewithmorethan1000 limit 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO some_table (some_column) 
    SELECT 'Sunday'
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d1
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d2
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d3
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d4
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d5
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d6
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d7
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d8
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d9
        JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d10
    ) AS t
    LIMIT 1000

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO some_table (some_column) 
SELECT 'Sunday' FROM ( SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d1 

JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d2 JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d3 
JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d4 JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d5 

JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d6 JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d7 
JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d8 JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d9 
JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) as d10 ) AS t LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

create a table with some `N` rows then cross join the `sunday` value with the 1000 rows.

```
select A.day_name from number_table
cross join (select 'sunday' as day_name) A
where num <= 1000
```

Comment: dude, "create a table with some N rows" is the problem he is asking to solve.  Well, not exactly, but hardly an improvement.

Comment: Anon316, the OP just asked to avoid loops, not temporary tables. @HmanshuUpadhyay, what error?

Comment: @underscore_d - first, your query does not even try to do an insert.  And creating a table with n rows is the problem he wanted to solve.  You are telling him the way to get 1000 inserts without loops is to first insert 1000 rows into a temp table, without loops.

Comment: My query? What query is that? Please show me where, in this thread, I have written a query. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this with stored procedure,

```
create table thousandvalues (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
weeks varchar(10)
); 

delimiter //
create procedure showthousand (in num int)
begin
declare i int default 0;
while i < num do
insert into thousandvalues (weeks) values ('sunday');
set i = i + 1;
end while;
end //
delimiter;

call showthousand (1000);
```

Hope it helps.